# Java's Character.isIdentifierPart() - what is the greatest integer to which the function gives "true"

Tags: java, unicode

I am new to Java - while reading, I understood that there are certain characters that cannot be used while naming Java identifier. While I agree that the characters available for use can be very limited due to the keyboards (not available in the keyboards), I wanted to know what are all the characters that Java can possibly take for an identifier. I wrote a code accordingly, and I used Character.isJavaIdentifierPart() - the problem is that I do not know what to use as the maximum int value for iteration. because setting the i value Character.MAXVALUE (is it dependent on the system used?) limits it to 65535, and I saw that there are characters beyond 65535. Can someone please help me with this.

```java
for(int i =0;i<Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {      
printWriter.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(i) + " " + (char) i + " " + i);
System.out.println(i);

}
```

In case I use 109385 instead of Character.MAX_VALUE, java still identifies certain characters that can be used in identifier beyond 65535- 
1. Can someone please let me know what is the maximum i value that I can use to identify all the characters that can be used for java identifier - and why?
2. Am I correct in understanding that because my Character.MAX_VALUE is 65355, I cannot store any character beyond that.

thanks!

Comment: The argument of isJavaIdentifierPart is of type `char`. A char is a 16-bits unsigned integer. Its values go from 0 to Character.MAX_VALUE. There is no other possible char value, otherwise you would need more than 16 bits to store them.

Comment: @JBNizet `isJavaIdentifierPart` has a variant that takes an `int`.

Comment: Oops, yes, missed that. Then if the goal is to check which integers are java identifier parts, all you need is to loop from Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @JBNizet technically Unicode starts with U+0 and (at least for now) promises it will never go beyond U+10FFFF

Comment: Sure. My point is that if you don't know that, then testing all the possible values of an int willl give you the answer you want.

Comment: Note that what you are testing are *code points*, not *characters*. Code points are outside the range for character - which applies both to your upper boundary, and to that cast you have in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode contains more than 65536 characters and new characters are added with every new version of Unicode.  So, meanwhile for any particular version of Unicode it is possible to identify valid Java identifier part character with biggest code, this value will probably be different for future versions, and `Character.MAX_CODE_POINT` is probably the only reliable upper boundary.

Comment: 0xf0000–0xfffff and 0x100000–0x10ffff are reserved as private use areas, so practically speaking, 0xeffff would be a reliable upper boundary.